# Controller fails if passed parm is "sys"

Tags: cakephp, request, cakephp-2.4

I am using a form in my index view to "GET" a query string for filtering my table.  I end up with a URL like this, "/teams?company=sun".

This one works OK I use "$this->request->query('company');" to get the value.  But if I change the parameter value to "sys" (e.g. company=sys) then I get a "404 - File or directory not found" error.  I presume sys or system is a reserved word which is causing a problem somewhere.

Is this a bug or is it behaviour that I could catch and override?

Comment: This must be a bug in your code. There is no such reserved word/functionality - anywhere in PHP or CakePHP.

Comment: I tried putting "exit();" into the controller and "index.php" to see if I could find the code where the error occurred. Even when I put it at the start of index.php the error still occurred.  I am thinking it is more an IIS or PHP problem.  I am using IIS 7.5 and php 5.4.  I checked the browser, it happens with Chrome and IE. Not a Cake problem.

Comment: I think it is IIS doing SQL Injection attack prevention.  The same thing happens if I use "drop" instead of "sys".  Under "Request Filtering" there is a "SQL Injection" rule that scans the query string.

Comment: I deleted the SQLInjection rule and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

IIS was doing SQLInjection attack prevention. I deleted the "SQLInjection" Rule from Request Filtering and it is working now.